# Azure cloud service app pool error

Tags: azure, iis

I'm trying to update a cloud service deployment on azure.
I can deploy fine to a test cloud service.
However, when I try to deploy to our production cloud service's staging slot the publish to azure from visual studio completes with no errors but in azure I don't see the new deployment in the staging slot.

I have verified that it deployed to the staging slot instances because I can Remote Desktop into each of the servers and see the new code in IIS.

The only errors I see are on the servers, where there are IIS event warnings regarding:
The application / belonging to site xxx has an invalid AppPoolId.
Site xxx was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid.
A process serving application pool xxx terminated unexpectedly.

Sure enough, when I browse the website the old site is running and not the new one.

Greatly appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Making sure we are on the same page...
- if you RDP into the staging deployment, you can verify that new code has been published
- when you browse to the website, you see the old code.

A couple of things to check...
When you say 'browse to the website', do you mean you attempted to reach the website via (1) a custom domain that points to the xxxxx.cloudapp.net, (2) directly at xxxx.cloudapp.net, or (3) {some long guid}.cloudapp.net?

Did you attempt to perform a VIP SWAP, and if so, when you click on SWAP, does the portal correctly reflect the date and time that the staging was deployed?

Comment: When I RDP into the staging deployment I do see the new code published, for example new image files that were in the new build that was deployed and the web.config is the newest version.  When I said 'browse to the website' what I meant is that I cohold update my local host file to point the production host name to the staging IP address to view the website, and I did verify that the browser was using the new IP address by using developer tools.  I haven't performed a SWAP.  The curious thing is that even though the publish to azure completed I don't see the deployment in the stage deployments

Comment: If it is harmless and you are SUPER CAREFUL, try deleting the Staging instance manually from the portal and then redeploy the staging again. The DELETE button allows to delete the production one too - SO PLEASE BE CAREFUL in selecting the Staging to delete. If all goes well, you should see Azure reporting that 'you have nothing deployed to the staging environment' and tehn upon deployment, it should pop up again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it didn't help. The UI did indicate that the 'deployment is transitioning', but once that finished I checked the deployments screen and there were no deployments listed. When I RDP into the staging server(s) I saw the same app pool error listed.